# How to bind one array of class on the same page but give each set of controls for one object same index ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to refactor some HTML Code from MVC Razor view and use it as partial view

```
@helper NotificationTemplateHTML(int i)
{
    <div class="tab-pane @Model.NotificationTemplates[i].ActiveCSSClass" id="@string.Format(@Model.NotificationTemplates[i].NotificationTypeString)">
        <p class="lead">
        </p>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].NotificationType)
        <p>

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].ParametersString, "Parameters")
                @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].ParametersString, false, true)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].IsStopped, "Stop sending")
                @Html.HTCheckedFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].IsStopped, "Stop sending", true)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].IsLogEnabled, "Log Notification")
                @Html.HTCheckedFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].IsLogEnabled, "Log Notification", true)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].SendingNotificationType, "Sending Options")
                @Html.HTMultiListFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].SendingNotificationType,
                    FillListHelper.GetList<SendingNotificationType_s_WS, SendingNotificationType_s>(), true)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MobileCC, "List mobile CC ',' seperated")
                @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MobileCC, false)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].EmailCC, "List Emails CC ',' seperated")
                @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].EmailCC, false)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MessageHeader, "Message Header Email")
                @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MessageHeader, false)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MessageBody, "Message Body Email")

                @Html.HTTextEditorFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MessageBody)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].SMSBody, "SMS Body")
                @Html.HTTextAreaFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].SMSBody)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].PushNotificationBody, "Push Notification Body")
                @Html.HTTextAreaFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].PushNotificationBody)
            </div>
            <p class="lead">
                Arabic Content
            </p>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MessageHeaderAr, "Message Header Email Arabic")
                @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MessageHeaderAr, false)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MessageBodyAr, "Message Body Email Arabic")
                @Html.HTTextEditorFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].MessageBodyAr)
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].SMSBodyAr, "SMS Body Arabic")
                @Html.HTTextAreaFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].SMSBodyAr)
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].PushNotificationBodyAr, "Push Notification Arabic")

                @Html.HTTextAreaFor(model => model.NotificationTemplates[i].PushNotificationBodyAr)
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

***The Binded HTML is generating control with ID Names in Diffrent name because it's Array***

So this this code is working fine but i want  to refactor this code  to be in partial view like this

```
@model BusinessLogic.Settings.NotificationTemplate

<div class="tab-pane @Model.ActiveCSSClass" id="@string.Format(@Model.NotificationTypeString)">
    <p class="lead">
    </p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NotificationType)
    <p>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.ParametersString, "Parameters")
            @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.ParametersString, false, true)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.IsStopped, "Stop sending")
            @Html.HTCheckedFor(model => model.IsStopped, "Stop sending", true)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.IsLogEnabled, "Log Notification")
            @Html.HTCheckedFor(model => model.IsLogEnabled, "Log Notification", true)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.SendingNotificationType, "Sending Options")
            @Html.HTMultiListFor(model => model.SendingNotificationType,
                    FillListHelper.GetList<SendingNotificationType_s_WS, SendingNotificationType_s>(), true)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.MobileCC, "List mobile CC ',' seperated")
            @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.MobileCC, false)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.EmailCC, "List Emails CC ',' seperated")
            @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.EmailCC, false)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.MessageHeader, "Message Header Email")
            @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.MessageHeader, false)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.MessageBody, "Message Body Email")

            @Html.HTTextEditorFor(model => model.MessageBody)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.SMSBody, "SMS Body")
            @Html.HTTextAreaFor(model => model.SMSBody)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.PushNotificationBody, "Push Notification Body")
            @Html.HTTextAreaFor(model => model.PushNotificationBody)
        </div>
    <p class="lead">
        Arabic Content
    </p>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.MessageHeaderAr, "Message Header Email Arabic")
        @Html.HTTextBoxFor(model => model.MessageHeaderAr, false)
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.MessageBodyAr, "Message Body Email Arabic")
        @Html.HTTextEditorFor(model => model.MessageBodyAr)
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.SMSBodyAr, "SMS Body Arabic")
        @Html.HTTextAreaFor(model => model.SMSBodyAr)
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @Html.HTLabelFor(model => model.PushNotificationBodyAr, "Push Notification Arabic")

        @Html.HTTextAreaFor(model => model.PushNotificationBodyAr)
    </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

**But the names of HTML Controls if Binded a array of the same objected NotificaitonTemplate Class has the same ID And Name so it will not work**

How can I Solve this

Comment: You make your partial an `EditorTemplate` (by naming it `NotificationTemplate.cshtml` and placing it in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` folder) and then use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.yourCollectionProperty)` to generate the correct html for each item in the `yourCollectionProperty`

Comment: [What are Display and Editor Templates?](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/)

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was on the Comment by Stephen Muecke
Thanks So much

You make your partial an EditorTemplate (by naming it NotificationTemplate.cshtml and placing it in the /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ folder) and then use @Html.EditorFor(m => m.yourCollectionProperty) to generate the correct html for each item in the yourCollectionProperty